# Rails 5 Integration test fails with NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass when using Devise helper sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, integration-testing, warden

I'm writing an integration test for Rails v5.1 using built-in Minitest.

Here's the integration test class:

```
require 'test_helper'

class PuppiesEndpointsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

    include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers

    test "DELETE puppy" do
        marty = people(:marty)

        sign_in(marty)

        # delete puppies_delete_path(marty.puppies.first.id)
        # delete `/api/v1/puppies/destroy/${marty.puppies.first.id}.json`
        # delete puppies_path(marty.puppies.first.id)
        delete '/api/v1/puppies/destroy/6666.json'
        assert_response :success
    end

end
```

All of the routes above, including the ones that are commented out, result in the same cryptic error:

```
Error:
PuppiesEndpointsTest#test_DELETE_puppy:
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
    test/integration/puppies_endpoints_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:PuppiesEndpointsTest>'


bin/rails test test/integration/puppies_endpoints_test.rb:7
```

It doesn't give a stack trace or any other information to diagnose what the hell it's talking about. I used byebug to debug the `marty` variable right before that `delete` line that's throwing the error. It shows the expected puppies array of associated (fixture) records.

I've also placed a byebug at the very top of the controller action and this error fails the test before it reaches that byebug, so I think that pretty much rules out anything in the action code.

Here's the relevant chunk of what I see when I run `rake routes`:

```
                       PATCH      /api/v1/puppies/edit/:id(.:format)        puppies#update
                       DELETE     /api/v1/puppies/destroy/:id(.:format)     puppies#destroy
        puppies_create POST       /api/v1/puppies/create(.:format)          puppies#create
```

Here's what is actually in the my routes file:

```
  scope '/api' do
    scope '/v1' do
      devise_for :people

      patch 'puppies/edit/:id' => 'puppies#update'
      delete 'puppies/destroy/:id' => 'puppies#destroy'#, as: 'puppies_delete'
      post 'puppies/create' => 'puppies#create'
      ...
```

I'm completely stumped as to what/why I'm getting this error. The actual code is working completely as expected.

My hunch is that maybe there's a missing config variable that's not getting set for the test environment (I use dotenv gem), but I have no idea how to track that down if the error won't give me any context whatsoever.

**UPDATE**

I have isolated this problem to using the Devise helper `sign_in` method. When I remove this method call, the problem goes away.

Here's the problematic test class:

```
require 'test_helper'

class PuppiesEndpointsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

    include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers

    test "do stuff" do
       ...
```

app/controllers/api_controller.rb:

```
class ApiController < ActionController::API
end
```

<s>Maybe `sign_in` does not work for testing controllers that do not inherit from ActionController::Base</s>

I changed the controller to inherit from `ActionController::Base` and nothing changed. I still can't use `sign_in` without getting that error, but it works find if I "manually" `post` a request to the sign_in endpoint.

**UPDATE 2**
I found this Devise issue which sounds related to my problem: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2065

Comment: Just curious that you created `marty = people(:marty)` and then used `emerson` to sign_in, is it intended?

Comment: Do you have any `before_action` filters for this action in controller?

Comment: there is to much code missing where it could come from. Have you tried putting `binding.pry` before `marty = people(:marty)` and doing hte commands manually to narrow down where the issue comes from?

Comment: @Hoa.Nguyen Sorry that was a copy/paste mistake. Fixed now

Comment: @Vasilisa That controller has: `before_action :authenticate_person!`

Comment: @DennyMueller I've been using `byebug` but it didn't think it could step into the integration helper methods... I'll try it.

Comment: @Vasilisa I tried the test with the before_action removed and nothing changed.

Comment: @emersonthis Which line is `puppies_endpoints_test.rb:17`?

Comment: @Vasilisa It's the `delete ...`

Comment: @emersonthis, what about another tests? Do you have any working tests for Api::V1::PuppiesController? Do you have any other working tests in Api::V1 namespace? I suppose Api::V1::PuppiesController inherits from some more general, eg BaseApiController - what about `before_action` there?

Comment: @Vasilisa this was my first test but I just added another one with a `post` to another action on the same controller and go the same error. Very interesting.

Comment: ApiController inherits from ActionController::API and the class has nothing in it. I do have another test for an action in another controller that also inherits from ApiController and that one passes as expected. It has the same before_action

Comment: @Vasilisa I noticed one difference between the passing tests file and the one that is doing the error. The failing test class has `include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers` and when I remove it the test fails (because the action requires authentication) but the original error goes away. I think we're getting close to the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like I found the [issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4696). Apparently, in rails-api mode, the ActionDispatch::Cookies and ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore middlewares are inserted in the end of the middleware stack, which doesn't occur in normal Rails mode.

Due to this, those middlewares are included after Warden::Manager which messes up something in request specs.

Try to set in test.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before Warden::Manager, ActionDispatch::Cookies
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before Warden::Manager, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
```

Comment: That was it! You nailed it. Thanks. Now that we figured this out, I might file an issue with the Devise project.

Comment: I see from your link it's already filed. Maybe I'll submit a PR to update the README

Comment: @emersonthis happy to help you! PR is a great idea, I think